# browser Back button in angular

Tags: angular

I have a page in that it show connected system names device page, user can click on any system it shows login dialog, on success.

1. List page  listPage connected system's product is listed , user
   can click on product item it navigate to  next page "product detail
   page"
2. Product Detail view  [Click on Next button], user navigate "Page C"
3. Page-c [Click on Complete Button]
                   [In this button handle, i will navigate to list page]
                       this.router.navigate(/listPage)
                       this.location.replaceState(/devices)
                   ]

Now,
        If the user click the back button form listPage, and once again click back button it navigate to /device page and once again if the user click back button. I expect it should go out of the application stack and it show  [initial screen assume google.com]
        But, in my case after clicking Complete button, page navigate to list view, and user click back button it shows device list, once again if i click back button, page wont navigate stay on the same page and once again i click back button it move to list view and once again i click back button, it moves to device page and once again back button its coming to google.com